# Using JUNG to find disconnected sub graph in a graph

Tags: java, graph, jung

I have created a graph using JUNG in java

```
Graph<Integer, String> g;
public SimpleGraphView2() {
    // Graph<V, E> where V is the type of the vertices and E is the type of the edges

    g = new SparseGraph<Integer, String>();
    // Add some vertices. From above we defined these to be type Integer.
    g.addVertex((Integer)1);
    g.addVertex((Integer)2);
    g.addVertex((Integer)3); 
    g.addVertex((Integer)4); 
    g.addVertex((Integer)5); 
    g.addVertex((Integer)6); 
    g.addVertex((Integer)7);
    g.addVertex((Integer)8); 

    g.addEdge("A", 1, 2);
    g.addEdge("B", 2, 3);  
    g.addEdge("C", 2, 4); 
    g.addEdge("D", 4, 5); 
    g.addEdge("E", 1, 3); 
    g.addEdge("F", 6, 7); 
    g.addEdge("G", 7, 8); 
}
```

I want to find the number of disconnected graphs in my created graph g . So in my case , I want an output of 2 (the 1st graph contain:1,2,3,4,5. The 2nd contain:6,7,8). Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Joshua gave you the correct answer. An example would be:

```
Transformer<Graph<V,E>, Set<Set<V>>> trns = new WeakComponentClusterer<V,E>();
Set<Set<V>> clusters = trns.transform(graph);
```

This will give you `clusters` which is a `Set` (collection) of `Sets` of vertices. Basically, it will look like:

```
{                                                    <---+
   {1,2,3},{4,5},       <--- a set of vertices           |
   {1,2},{3},{5},                                        |- a set of sets
   {1},{2,3,4},                                          |
   ...                                                   |
}                                                    <---+
```

As an aside, the speed of this algorithm will depend on the number of vertices you have (as you correctly stated) as well as the number of edges. But 100,000 vertices shouldn't be a limiting factor.

Comment: Nice job, I will test this later

Comment: The output example seems to show the same vertex in multiple clusters but if that were the case then they wouldn't be clusters? When I run the example in the question with the transform in this answer I get `[[6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]` as the stringified value of `clusters`.

Comment: @mab It's been awhile since I've dealt with this but I believe that some algorithms group the same vertex into multiple clusters. I may be wrong but it was always an easy assumption to make that didn't seem to have many drawbacks at the time.

Comment: The weak (or strong) components of a graph partition the graph nodes, that is, each node is always assigned to exactly one component (cluster).  There are probabilistic clustering algorithms that assign probabilities to cluster/node assignments, but I'm not immediately aware of any clustering algorithms that straight-up assign a single node to multiple clusters.

Answer (score 3):

You want WeakComponentClusterer: http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/WeakComponentClusterer.html

Comment: of course I know this, I need example, the document is not well organized. I am a starter in java , example is what I need. Btw , keep in mind that my graph contains over 100.000 nodes

Answer (score 2):

Simple BFS will give you the answer...start your BFS from any node you will find all the nodes reachable from it..then again start BFS from another another node which has not been visited and so on...

Comment: I think JUNG have some library to do that but I am now sure , cause I am new to JUNG. Maybe can use somthing like clustering http://jung.sourceforge.net/doc/api/edu/uci/ics/jung/algorithms/cluster/package-summary.html or edu.uci.ics.jung.algorithms.connectivity.KNeighborhoodExtractor but I don't know how to use. SOme sample code would be appreciated